# Genetic blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, meta-transactions, white-paper

Admittedly vague question, but I hope this is on to something here.

I think blockchains depend on an “incentive”, of some kind (viewed abstractly).

Genetic algorithms also have some “evaluation criterion”. It sort of acts like a “sieve”, sifting a space of all (stochastically generated) possibilities for one that meets a condition (like maximizing or optimizing the evaluation - ie, a design for something that is fast, lightweight, etc.)

I think the difference might be, a blockchain chooses a structure with an incentive, in order to do work. A genetic algorithm chooses a “meta-structure” (for finding a structure, in turn), and an incentive. Someone “doing work” is presumed, in running a genetic algorithm.

What if you could put them together?

What if there was an incentive to develop a system, but the system itself was open to specification. Whoever developed the most optimal system, under the evaluation criterion, gets the rewards, of the blockchain.

It can remain dynamic: the resources of the game (perhaps, money, tokens?) are allocated (distributed, proportionally), to whatever “system” published on the chain is found to score highest under the blockchain’s evaluation criterion…

So somehow, it’s like a blockchain in that there is an incentive to “do work” (run servers to do the network’s computations; try to publish submissions to the network that score highly), but there is a second effect where the minimal criteria defining the network act as a self-organizing system that creates and tunes optimal designs - for itself.

It’s like a blockchain that does not choose a specific protocol, but has a weak meta-protocol which causes contributors to find protocols, and the blockchain selects the most optimal ones: then, those protocols are actively used, for some specific purpose, on that chain, to do actually useful real world “work” (it could be anything, like a blockchain for a local bus system, or whatever).

I assume someone is researching this, I’d appreciate some help in clarifying the terminology to find out what it is, how it could work, or be modeled mathematically.